# Default Double type element to null in CXF

Tags: jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java

I am using CXF wsdl2java and have below complexType in my schema:

```
 <complexType name="ABCType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="xxx" type="int"   maxOccurs="1"
            minOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="yyy" type="double" maxOccurs="1"
            minOccurs="0">
        </element>
</complexType>
```

Below is the class generated:

```
public class ABCType
implements Serializable
{

private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected Integer xxx;
protected Double yyy;



public Double getYYY() {
    return yyy;
}


public void setYYY(Double value) {
    this.yyy= value;
}
}
```

When I generate Java Class for above complexType. I see that "yyy" property is of Double type. How can I ask CXF to default "yyy" value to be null instead of 0.0, when yyy element is not present as part of request.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the generated Java class?

Comment: Ian i have added the class above, its not really the actual class but code generated is same.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the above code is generated. cxf codegen generates primitive type if field is required(min=1,max=1) and wrapper type if its optional(min=0 and max=1). And in java reference types are   initialized to null. Hence yyy would be null

Anyways if you need to add a default value in primitive type say suppose for below xsd

```
<element name="xxx" type="int"   maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" default="4" >
```

You can add default generator extension to cxf-codegen plugin as below

```
                 <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-sources</id>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <wsdlOptions>
                                        <wsdlOption>
                                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/mywsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
                                            <extraargs>
                                                <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                                <extraarg>-xjc-Xdv</extraarg>
                                            </extraargs>
                                        </wsdlOption>
                                    </wsdlOptions>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-dv</artifactId>
                                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
```